# How to create underline effect on hovered links in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve styling like this:

[image: bbc.com with arrows pointing to underlined menu entries]

How do I to create that effect using CSS?

Comment: there are several options.
1.add css property ``text-decoration:underline`` to your anchor tag on hover.
2.add css property ``border-bottom: 1px solid black`` to your anchor tag on hover.

Comment: On hover add `border-bottom: 4px solid #f00` and reduce padding as `padding:2px 0;` in inner element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a{
   text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

This should work for links, however the effect in the picture seems to be made with the link's container border:

```
div.yourcontainer:hover{
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
```

This should work ^^

Answer (score 3):

By using `:hover` and setting a `border-bottom`. Something like this

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: black;
}
ul li:hover{
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
 a {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    a:hover:before {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 0 #11c0e5;
    }

    a span {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: red;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="#">
    <span>link texts</span>
    </a>
```

Comment: added a runnable snippet to my answer

Comment: Can u tell me more about inset? I mean why did we put it there.

Comment: inset makes the shadow from an outer shadow to an inner shadow which fits with the requirements of the question. bear in mind if you use box-shadow without inset, it'd create a shadow outside the link